# Cannot find SignedCms class in .NET Core Source Browser anymore

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, reference, frameworks

Few days ago I was able to view [SignedCms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.pkcs.signedcms) class and other related classes in [System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.pkcs) namespace through [.NET Core Source Browser](https://source.dot.net/#q=SignedCms), but now I cannot find any class from System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs namespace in .NET Core Source Browser anymore.

Using .NET Core Source Browser it was easy for me to find all references to some member and generally move through code with a need to download anything.

[.NET Framework Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Security/system/security/cryptography/pkcs/signedpkcs7.cs,450a89c7062d7944) still contains SignedCms class, but that implementation is not cross-platform and doesn't interest me.

Doesn't anyone know why this is happening?

Is this maybe because [.NET Core FX](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx) repository was moved to [.NET Runtime](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime) repository?

It would also be nice that layout of .NET Core Source Browser is adaptive. When I view it on my iPad, the list view from the left part occupies half of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I also asked this question in SourceBrowser repository: https://github.com/KirillOsenkov/SourceBrowser/issues/137.

There seems to be some internal problem with building projects from runtime repository after its versions got updated.